# How to derive the dual for Parabolic Relaxation for QCQPs

Tags: convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, semidefinite-programming, qcqp

I'm reading this [paper (EQ 11/15/16)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.03622.pdf) on a way to relax QCQPs. They state the dual of their program, but I can't quite figure out how they got there.

We're minimizing over variables: $X$ (PSD $n\times n$), $Y\in\mathbb R^{n\times m}$  ($m\le n$). For some symmetric matrices $A_i$ and $B_i\in \mathbb R^{n\times m}$.
The primal is:
\begin{align*}
&\text{minimize}_{X,Y}&& \langle A_0, X\rangle + 2\langle B_0, Y\rangle +c_0\\
&\text{Subject to}&& \langle A_i, X\rangle + 2\langle B_i, Y\rangle +c_i\\
&&&(e_k+e_\ell)^T X(e_k+e_\ell)\ge \Vert(e_i+e_j)^T Y\Vert\\
&&&(e_k-e_\ell)^T X(e_k-e_\ell)\ge \Vert(e_i-e_j)^T Y\Vert\\
\end{align*}
where the $e_i$ form the standard basis for $\mathbb R^n$ and $k,\ell\in [n]$.

The dual is a maximization over $t_i\in \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ and symmetric $m\times m$ matrices $T$:

\begin{align*}
    &\text{minimize}_{t, T} &&\text{tr}(T)\\
    &\text{subject to}&&\begin{bmatrix}
     A_0&B_0\\
B_0^T&+-T+m^{-1}c_0I_m
\end{bmatrix} + \sum_{i}t_i\begin{bmatrix}
A_i&B_i\\
B^T_i&m^{-1}c_kI_m
\end{bmatrix}\succeq 0\\
&&&[e_1,\dots, e_n]^T\left(A_0+\sum_i t_kA_k\right)[e_1,\dots, e_n]\in \mathbb D_n,
\end{align*}
where $\mathbb D_n$ is the set of $n\times n$ diagonally dominant matrices.

The PSD constraint makes sense to me, but I'm not sure how the last constraint is derived!

I'm just using the Lagrangian, but I don't understand why there's not a dependence on the $B_i$ matrices.

Thanks!